# Select particular fields from Json

Tags: android

```
[
  {
    "cid": "1",
    "course_name": "CS",
    "subcode": "CS-601",
    "subname": "Microprocessor",
    "semester": "6"
  },
  {
    "cid": "2",
    "course_name": "CS",
    "subcode": "CS-602",
    "subname": "PPL",
    "semester": "6"
  },
  {
    "cid": "3",
    "course_name": "CS",
    "subcode": "CS-604",
    "subname": "computer networking",
    "semester": "6"
  },
  {
    "cid": "4",
    "course_name": "CS",
    "subcode": "CS-603",
    "subname": "software Engineering",
    "semester": "6"
  },
  {
    "cid": "5",
    "course_name": "CS",
    "subcode": "CS-601[P]",
    "subname": "Microprocessor practical",
    "semester": "6"
  },
  {
    "cid": "6",
    "course_name": "CS",
    "subcode": "CS-604[P]",
    "subname": "Computer networking practical",
    "semester": "6"
  },
  {
    "cid": "22",
    "course_name": "ME",
    "subcode": "ME-301",
    "subname": "motar",
    "semester": "3"
  },
  {
    "cid": "23",
    "course_name": "ME",
    "subcode": "ME-302",
    "subname": "friction",
    "semester": "3"
  },
  {
    "cid": "24",
    "course_name": "ME",
    "subcode": "ME-301[P]",
    "subname": "motar practical",
    "semester": "3"
  },
  {
    "cid": "25",
    "course_name": "ME",
    "subcode": "ME-302[P]",
    "subname": "friction practical",
    "semester": "3"
  },
  {
    "cid": "26",
    "course_name": "CE",
    "subcode": "CE-701",
    "subname": "Design of hydraulic Structure",
    "semester": "7"
  },
  {
    "cid": "27",
    "course_name": "CE",
    "subcode": "CE-702",
    "subname": "Advances Structrued design 2",
    "semester": "7"
  },
  {
    "cid": "28",
    "course_name": "CE",
    "subcode": "CE-701[P]",
    "subname": "Design of hydraulic Structure practical",
    "semester": "7"
  },
  {
    "cid": "29",
    "course_name": "CE",
    "subcode": "CE-702[P]",
    "subname": "Advances Structrued design 2 practical",
    "semester": "7"
  },
  {
    "cid": "45",
    "course_name": "AU",
    "subcode": "AU-502",
    "subname": "AUTOMATION TOOL",
    "semester": "1"
  }
]
```

Comment: What dod you try? What is the issue with it?

Comment: Show us your effort, dude.

Comment: having trouble in finding out how to fecth particular data from the coloum

Comment: so please update your question ...

Answer (score -1):

I will show my idea to you. Wish these can help you.From China.

```js
var arr = [{"cid":"1","course_name":"CS","subcode":"CS-601","subname":"Microprocessor","semester":"6"},{"cid":"2","course_name":"CS","subcode":"CS-602","subname":"PPL","semester":"6"},{"cid":"3","course_name":"CS","subcode":"CS-604","subname":"computer networking","semester":"6"},{"cid":"4","course_name":"CS","subcode":"CS-603","subname":"software Engineering","semester":"6"},{"cid":"5","course_name":"CS","subcode":"CS-601[P]","subname":"Microprocessor practical","semester":"6"},{"cid":"6","course_name":"CS","subcode":"CS-604[P]","subname":"Computer networking practical","semester":"6"},{"cid":"22","course_name":"ME","subcode":"ME-301","subname":"motar","semester":"3"},{"cid":"23","course_name":"ME","subcode":"ME-302","subname":"friction","semester":"3"},{"cid":"24","course_name":"ME","subcode":"ME-301[P]","subname":"motar practical","semester":"3"},{"cid":"25","course_name":"ME","subcode":"ME-302[P]","subname":"friction practical","semester":"3"},{"cid":"26","course_name":"CE","subcode":"CE-701","subname":"Design of hydraulic Structure","semester":"7"},{"cid":"27","course_name":"CE","subcode":"CE-702","subname":"Advances Structrued design 2","semester":"7"},{"cid":"28","course_name":"CE","subcode":"CE-701[P]","subname":"Design of hydraulic Structure practical","semester":"7"},{"cid":"29","course_name":"CE","subcode":"CE-702[P]","subname":"Advances Structrued design 2 practical","semester":"7"},{"cid":"45","course_name":"AU","subcode":"AU-502","subname":"AUTOMATION TOOL","semester":"1"}];

var arrIncludeCS = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if( arr[i].course_name =="CS"){
      arrIncludeCS.push(arr[i])
   }
}
console.log(arrIncludeCS)
```

Run code snippet and you will see a new JSON.